# Have a variable in images path in Sass?

Tags: css, sass

I want to have one variable that contains the root path to all my images in my CSS file. I can't quite figure out if this is possible in pure Sass (the actual web project is not RoR, so can't use asset_pipeline or any of that fancy jazz).

Here's my example that doesn't work. On compile it balks at first instance of variable in the background url property saying (`"Invalid CSS after "..site/background": expected ")"`).

Defining the function to return the path:

```
//Vars
$assetPath : "/assets/images";

//Functions
@function get-path-to-assets($assetPath){
  @return $assetPath;
}
```

Using the function:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url($get-path-to-assets/site/background.jpg) repeat-x fixed 0 0;
  width: 100%; }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Have you tried the [Interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) syntax?

```
background: url(#{$get-path-to-assets}/site/background.jpg) repeat-x fixed 0 0;
```

Comment: It does not work for me because CssVariablesProcessor does not process variables even if its set as preprocessor before CssDataUriPreProcessor

Comment: Also works in quoted paths e.g. in the compass font-face mixin.
`'#{$fontName}.ext', ..`

Comment: Yes, it is better to use in quoted path. Other wise it shows error in netbeans IDE.
url("#{$get-path-to-assets}/site/background.jpg")

Answer (score 106):

No need for a function:

```
$assetPath : "/assets/images";

...

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(#{$assetPath}/site/background.jpg) repeat-x fixed 0 0;
  width: 100%; }
```

See the [interpolation docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) for details.

Comment: Definitely prefer the brevity with pointing directly to the variable

Comment: if you are using it at an @import you need to add 'url(' and ')' to make the interpolation to work. More info at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#plain-css-imports

Answer (score 6):

Was searching around for an answer to the same question, but think I found a better solution: http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/compass/image-url/

Basically, you can set your image path in config.rb and you use the image-url() helper

Answer (score 3):

Adding something to the above correct answers. I am using netbeans IDE and it shows error while using `url(#{$assetPath}/site/background.jpg)` this method. It was just netbeans error and no error in sass compiling. But this error break code formatting in netbeans and code become ugly. But when I use it inside quotes like below, it show wonder!

`url("#{$assetPath}/site/background.jpg")`

Answer (score 1):

We can use relative path instead of absolute path:

```
$assetPath: '~src/assets/images/';
$logo-img: '#{$assetPath}logo.png';
@mixin logo {
  background-image: url(#{$logo-img});
}

.logo {
    max-width: 65px;
    @include logo;
 }
```