# Sass function return multiple font urls

Tags: css, sass

I Created conditional **SCSS function** for return single or multiple font urls.

And my compiled css looking without errors. So i seems the function is working well.

**But when press F5 to debug, in the console giving an error (in nodejs app)**

> error: error reading values after

After the error my site is looking bad. So i opened css file in my site using developer tools, in the css file looking like this

> error reading values after 
>       1
>       Error: error reading values after

*It seems css file doesn't compiled. But locally i opened it, then looking well*

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Sansation_Regular";
    src: url("../fonts/Sansation_Regular.ttf"), url("../fonts/Sansation_Regular.eot"), url("../fonts/Sansation_Regular.woff"), url("../fonts/Sansation_Regular.svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If my function have problems help to solve.

**Here My SCSS Function**

```
@function urls($url, $multiple) {

    $result: ();

    // base url 
    $fontsBaseURL: '../fonts/';

    @if $multiple == true {

        $ext: "url(" + $fontsBaseURL + $url + ".ttf)" + ",",
              "url(" + $fontsBaseURL + $url + ".eot)" + ",",
              "url(" + $fontsBaseURL + $url + ".woff)" + ",",
              "url(" + $fontsBaseURL + $url + ".svg)";

        @each $item in $ext {
            $result: append($result, $item);
        }

        @return $result;
    } @else {
        @return url($fontsBaseURL + $url + .ttf);
    }
}
```

**And Helper `@mixin` Function**

```
@mixin Font($family, $src-name, $multiple) {
    $url: urls($src-name, $multiple);

    font-family: $family;   
    src: $url;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**Here i called Function**

```
@font-face {
    @include Font("Sansation_Regular", "Sansation_Regular", true);
}
```

Comment: I am voting to close this as a typographical error.  You've already demonstrated how to do this when declaring your $ext variable, the return inside of your else needs to be done the same way.

Comment: @shennan This isn't a "string concatenation" issue, it's an "I forgot that I that I need to quote strings that contain certain characters" issue.  Using the plus operator on 2 strings will concatenate them, to say "that's not how you do it" is nonsense.

Comment: @cimmanon I think this is still classed as a string concatenation issue, in the sense that, in your own words, "certain characters" need to be concatenated in certain ways. And I don't think that "forgetting" something qualifies for a downvote. We are here to help the unknown ***and*** the forgotten.

Comment: @shennan You should have voted to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608498/have-a-variable-in-images-path-in-sass

Comment: @cimmanon Is that why you voted to close on "off topic, because..."? Why not just vote to close as a duplicate yourself? Your assertion in your original comment that the `$ext` variable was declared properly was wrong. Your last comment is damage limitation IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your Sass Function to this:

```
@function urls($url, $multiple) {

    $result: ();

    // base url 
    $fontsBaseURL: '../fonts/';

    @if $multiple == true {

        @each $item in ('.ttf', '.eot', 'woff', '.svg') {

            $result: append($result, url('#{$fontsBaseURL}#{$url}#{$item}'), 'comma');
        }

        @return $result;
    } @else {
        @return url('#{$fontsBaseURL}#{$url}.tff');
    }
}
```

***Detailed Explanation:***

Remember that certain string concatenations are best done by wrapping the variable in `#{}` in Sass. Take a property value like `url('path/to/image.png');`. If we were to do the following:

```
body {
  $base: 'path/to/';
  $img: 'image.png';
  background-image: "url('" + $base + $img + "');"
}
```

The output would be:

```
body {
  background-image: "url('path/to/image.png');";
}
```

Which is technically wrong, as it is interpreted as a string as opposed to a CSS property value. To make this right, we might just attempt to declare the value without quotes, and use our variable concatenations as normal:

```
body {
  $base: 'path/to/';
  $img: 'image.png';
  background-image: url('$base + $img');
}
```

This is ***again*** wrong, because our variables are printed literally in the Sass output:

```
body {
  background-image: url("$base + $img");
}
```

What we really need, is a way of concatenating strings and expressions interchangeably. This is where the `#{}` is useful. Here is how you would achieve the above:

```
body {
  $base: 'path/to/';
  $img: 'image.png';
  background-image: url('#{$base}#{$img}');
}
```

Output:

```
p {
  background-image: url("path/to/image.png");
}
```

As an aside, you were also appending multiple font formats unnecessarily. Simply using a list in the declaration of the `@each` loop would have sufficed.

Comment: Love to know the reason for downvote...

Comment: great answer very helpful +1

Comment: @shennan your answer is worked. But need little bit changes. Thanks