# sass: Invalid CSS after "...: ": expected "}", was "url('...")

Tags: sass

I want to use a css custom property to store the url of an image. The following  works fine if I use css only:

```
html {
    --header-logo-img: url('/static/assets/images/logo.svg');
}
```

when I use the same in an scss file and compile it with sass I get an error:

> Line 2: Invalid CSS after "...ader-logo-img: ": expected "}", was
>   "url('/static/as...").

There is nothing else in my scss file.  (I tried it with a .sass file as well, same result).

The issue occurs only in combination with url. Assigning a color value or some such works fine.

News: It turns out that the error only appears if the path is set in either double or single quotation marks. This compiles happily:

```
html {
    --header-logo-img: url(/static/assets/images/logo.svg);
}
```

The question remains: Why does sass not like quotes here?  (Perhaps I should add that I am on sass 3.5.1.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a variable in images path in Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608498/have-a-variable-in-images-path-in-sass)

Comment: In my experience, errors like this are typically in the code above the line returned as an error. And it's usually something minor (like a missing semi-colon). We need a lot more of the related code to debug it for you.

Comment: @Obsidian Age: I do not see how interpolation syntax would help me since I don't use any sass variables here. What would you change?

@ elbrant1: It happens when this is the complete code. Only one scss file. No other files or code lines.