# Problem with css variable and jekyll to post site on github pages

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I have a problem with GitHub pages, SASS, CSS, and Jekyll. I declared some CSS variables for colors and files using `--[variable name]: variable value` for example:

```
--logo_light: url("../img/logo-desktop.svg") no-repeat;
--crearGifo_light: url("../img/button-crear-gifo.svg") no-repeat;
--crearGifoHover_light: url("../img/CTA-crear-gifo-hover.svg") no-repeat;
```

The issue is that GitHub is giving me the following error when I try to use Github pages to post the site:
[image]

```
 Your site is having problems building: Your SCSS file styles/styles.scss has an error on line 26: Invalid CSS after " --logo_light: ": expected "}", was "url("../img/log...". For more information, see https://docs.github.com/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#invalid-sass-or-scss.
```

I checked the docs but I couldn't find the solution, I tried adding `{{ variable value }}` to the values of the variables like it says in the docs but it didn't work, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

REPO:
https://github.com/nicolaszuleta95/Proyecto2_Acamica_GIFOS

Comment: Similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608498/have-a-variable-in-images-path-in-sass)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the relative path in the sass file. Try changing ../ to /. I mean start with root and use the appropriate path and see if it works.

Comment: Tried changing the paths like you said but I get the same error

Comment: Did you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608498/have-a-variable-in-images-path-in-sass

Comment: yes, checked that link tried to use that syntax but didnt work